# Regex in AngularJS, UI freezes

Tags: regex

I am using following regex to validate email. UI freezes while typing in. Thanks in advance

```
'^(?!.*([.+_-])\\1)((?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.+_-]*)*[a-zA-Z0-9])+@((?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9-]*)*[a-zA-Z0-9])(?:\\.(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*){2,63})+$'
```

Comment: On http://regexr.com/ this does not match the email pattern

Comment: It is catastrophic backtracking, `aaa.abc@gmail.more_here.com` already causes it.

Comment: I do not understand what you want to match with `(?:\.(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*){2,63})+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case of catastrophic backtracking caused by a quantified group of quantified patterns where the first is obligatory and the second is optional.

Basically, you may replace

```
((?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.+_-]*)*[a-zA-Z0-9])+
```

with

```
[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9.+_-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

and your pattern will stop freezing the code execution. However, the trailing part `(?:\\.(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*){2,63})+` also looks strange. You may reduce it to `(?:\\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)+` since the `{2,63}` restriction does not make sense here.

Use

```
'^(?!.*([.+_-])\\1)[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9.+_-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)+$'
```